# How can I assign a script programmatically to a click on specific text (paragraph) in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm curious if there is a way to create a text in Google Docs and assign a script function to be called on click on this text.

I need to create text as well as assign function call to it both programmatically.

Comment: can you explain more about what you mean- click on text? Are you trying to click a link? Or Highlight text?

Comment: @OblongMedulla I mean a click on a link to call script function

Comment: I am not sure you can, are you aware you can create a drawing box and add text on it. And set that to fun function on click?

Comment: @OblongMedulla I consider this approach if there is no way to do it with links. But that's the second part of question - I couldn't find a way to set onclick function to a drawing box.

Comment: After you create the drawing click on the arrow in upper right of the drawing and assign script. And set the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drawing and assign a function to it on click.
After you create a drawing select the arrow. Then, assign Function

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it there a way to programmatically assign script to a programmatically created drawing?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible. Perhaps someone else may know.